# Render is not working in node.js while using express routing using the parameters in the link. If I remove the css file linked in head it is working

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

```
app.get("/posts/:postName", (req, res) => {
    var orgpost = req.params.postName;
    posts.forEach(post => {
        if (orgpost === post.post_title) {
            res.render("post", {
                req_title: post.post_title,
                req_body: post.post_body

            });
        }
    });
});
```

The render here is not working!! Except this all are working

Comment: Try to verify that `orgpost === post.post_title` actually evaluates to `true`.

Comment: If there is more than one `post` whose `post_title` equals `orgpost`, `res.render` will be called more than once, which leads to the error "Cannot set headers after they are sent".

Comment: Yes it is. It's not working if I link css file in the head section. But I unlink the css file it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. If it’s just the CSS, a common issue I read was putting a ‘/’ in front of the link to your local folder. If yours looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

then add this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

Otherwise, I had a similar issue, but I found that it was because we are using `res` and how the middleware behaves. Here’s a good explanation on how to use the Node/Express response methods in this well written [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7789131/17994178).

Basically, within your `forEach` loop you are only rendering something for the *if* statement but not the *else* statement. It has to do with the middleware items and how they respond problematically when they can’t call `response.end()` but your loop is forcing continuous iterations, and so you’ll be endlessly loading. This is probably why when I stopped Node I found that it would actually render my page.

Here is the solution that worked for me and adapted for your code:

```js
app.get('/posts/:postName', (req, res) => {
  const orgpost = req.params.postName;
  let pageFound = false;
  posts.forEach(post => {
    if (orgpost === post.post_title) {
      pageFound = true;
      console.log("Match found!")
      res.render('post', {
        req_title: post.post_title,
        content: post.post_body
      });
    }
  });
  if (!pageFound) {
    console.log("Not a match");
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

By using `res` outside of the `forEach` loop, when we do our request it doesn't loop. In this case I used `res.redirect()`.